# MySQL How can I make a better query to connect two tables through my bridge table?

Tags: mysql, database, bridge, select-query

I have these tables:

words:

```
+----+------+
| ID | DATA |
+----+------+
|  1 | jo   |
|  2 | yes  |
|  3 | jupp |
|  4 | yeah |
|  5 | jepp |
|  6 | joah |
|  7 | ne   |
|  8 | nee  |
|  9 | no   |
| 10 | nope |
| 11 | nah  |
+----+------+
```

statements:

```
+----+------+
| ID | DATA |
+----+------+
|  1 | ja   |
|  2 | nein |
+----+------+
```

and a bridge table that connects the words from table "words" with the DATA from table "statements":

bridge:

```
+--------------+---------+
| ID_statement | ID_word |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 |       1 |
|            1 |       2 |
|            1 |       3 |
|            1 |       4 |
|            1 |       6 |
|            2 |       8 |
|            2 |       9 |
+--------------+---------+
```

I wanted to get a SELECT QUERY to get all words associated with the statement "ja".

this query does the job, but seems more complicated than it should be:

```
SELECT words.DATA FROM words 
 JOIN bridge ON words.ID = bridge.ID_word 
 JOIN statements ON statements.ID = bridge.ID_statement 
 WHERE statements.ID = (
 SELECT ID FROM statements WHERE statements.DATA = "ja"
 );
```

Intuition tells me that I am doing that far to comlicated, but I can't figure out where the complication lies.
awkward.

Comment: another question but slightly off topic would be: how would one describe the relationship here? one-to-many? the relationship between words and statements seems to be one to many (only one statement fits many words that can be synonyms). only thing is that i only learned to know about bridge tables in the context of many-to-many relationships. is my db design flawed in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to name the primary keys the same as the columns that reference them. So in your example, in the `words` table, you'd name the primary key `ID_word`. In the `statements` table, you'd name the primary key `ID_statement`.

The advantage is that you can make your SQL join a little more concise with the `USING(...)` syntax. This syntax assumes there's a column by that name in both tables of a join, and you want the join to match where the column is equal to the same column in the other table.

```
SELECT words.DATA FROM words 
 JOIN bridge USING (ID_word) 
 JOIN statements USING (ID_statement) 
 WHERE statements.DATA = 'ja';
```

Also you don't need to run a subquery in your example. The rows in statement matching the IDs from the rows in statement where `DATA='ja'` are the same set as the rows in statement where `DATA='ja'`.

> how would one describe the relationship here? one-to-many?

The relationship modeled by a bridge table is a *many-to-many* relationship. The specific data in your example doesn't show it, but it's possible that many different statements could reference the same word. What you do show is that each statement can reference many words.

Comment: thx. that helped a lot and really makes my life easier. i never got the USING syntax. 

about the relationship-naming: so that means that you'd only describe the table's relationships and not the relationships of the data? or would it change when i would define ID_words in the bridge table as Primary Key (which my example data would allow so far)?

Comment: @gauguerilla: If a row in `words` can be associated to at most one row `statement`, that's a one-to-many relationship, and a "bridge" table isn't necessary. You could instead add a foreign key column/constraint to the `words` table, referencing the primary key of the `statements` table. If a row in `words` isn't associated with a row in `statements`, then assign a NULL value to the foreign key column. This design would satisfy the example data. But as Bill noted, we can't make a determination that this is a one-to-many relationship. (The absence of a counter example is insufficient.)

Comment: What @spencer7593 said.